# How to use HTML data from ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, json

i have a load more button on some content that is pulled from a database via ajax.

The ajax call looks like so:

```
// JavaScript Document
// load more builds function
$(document).ready(function(){
var pageIndex = 1;
$('#loadmorebuilds-div').click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'includes/loadmorebuilds.php?type=' + type + '&pageIndex=' + pageIndex,
        success: function(html) {
            $("#buildcontainer").append(html).waterfall('reflow');
            $("#loadmorebuilds-div").stop().fadeOut();
            pageIndex++;

            var rowCount = MAKE THIS THE VALUE THAT IS APPENDED;
            $('.testcount').html(rowCount);
            if (rowCount < 18) {
                $('#loadmorebuilds-div').remove(); 
                $('.countvar').detach();
            } else {
                $('.countvar').detach();
            }
        }
    });
});
});
```

In the appended items, is a div that contains a value of the row count for the database query that has been carried out via the above ajax call.

Normally, i would put this value into a JSON return and simply do e.g.:

```
rowCount = response.rowCount
```

However i am not using a JSON datatype but HTML.

How can i get this value from the appended div in the data and use it to set a var?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use either:

```
val = $("#thatDiv").text();
```

or

```
val = $("#thatDiv").attr("value");
```

The latter of which, is if you put the value in a pseudo attribute...

Comment: I had that originally, but think issues were being caused because if the button remained, then more data could be appended and there for be multiple instances of that div on the page. Im going to try remove() the current (if any) instance of that count div before the ajax call is made.

Comment: That worked fine. Sometimes i think i should just type up a question but not actually post it. As soon as i post a question i figure it out myself :) I shall mark your answer as correct. It does answer my question.

Comment: oh cool- thanks - heh, yeah, I did that myself, yesterday ! I was about to go through a few other ways of doing it -! but I'm glad that worked -!